# Iteration through string and remove all instances of

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, iteration, charat

My instructions were to iterate through a string and remove all instances of the letter "a". I thought that it would be easy to find examples, but I was unable to do so. Some would remove the letter without the iteration, but that is not what the instructions asked. If someone could please look at my code and assist me in my task I would greatly appreciate it! The "removeA" function will iterate through the string now, and only console logs the !== "a", but for the life of me I can't figure out how to save it to a new string. Thanks in advance.

```
removeA = function(stringWithA) {
    if (stringWithA === null || typeof (stringWithA) !== "string" || stringWithA === "") {  //Checking for is null AND is not array
        return 'Please enter a valid string';
    } else {
        lowerWithA = stringWithA.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < lowerWithA.length; i++) {
            if (lowerWithA.charAt(i) !== "a") {
                console.log(lowerWithA.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, other than pointing out that you are not doing a removal in your logic any where, the one pointer I would give you, since this is homework, is you should iterate from the end to the beginning.

Comment: @Taplar - Good advice for in-place removal. This could also be done by creating a new string made of all characters but the undesired one(s).

Comment: @Bucket There is no such thing as "in-place" removal with strings. Strings are immutable, you can never do an "in-place" operation on a string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus. You're right. I lost the javascript context when I was thinking that through. In-place removal would be possible if you convert the string to an array of characters, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not build a new string with all the characters that are not `a`?

```
var newString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < lowerWithA.length; i++) {
    var letter = lowerWithA.charAt(i);
    if (letter !== "a") {
        newString += letter;
    }
}

console.log(newString);
```

If you wanted to expand this to be case-insensitive:

```
...
if (letter !== 'a' || letter !== 'A') { ... }
```

And simply don't call `String.toLowerCase()` on the original string.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the letters into an Array.

```js
var removeA = function(stringWithA) {

  if (stringWithA === null || typeof(stringWithA) !== "string" || stringWithA === "") { //Checking for is null AND is not array
    return 'Please enter a valid string';
  } else {
    var newString = [];
    lowerWithA = stringWithA.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < lowerWithA.length; i++) {
      if (lowerWithA.charAt(i) !== "a") {
        newString.push(lowerWithA.charAt(i))
      }
    }
    
    return newString.join('');
  }
}

console.log(removeA("Eleazar"))
```

Or, just use a `regex`:

```js
var removeA = function(stringWithA) {
  if (stringWithA === null || typeof(stringWithA) !== "string" || stringWithA === "") { //Checking for is null AND is not array
    return 'Please enter a valid string';
  } else {
    return stringWithA.replace(/a/gi, '')
  }
}

console.log(removeA("EleaaaaazAreeeeaaaElAAAAAeaaaEleEvene"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there's already a function that you need, `replace`:

```js
var stringWithA = 'A aaaa bbbcc!';
alert(stringWithA.replace(/[Aa]/g, ''));
```

Comment: OP states that he's seen solutions that don't involve iteration and that's not acceptable because the assignment was to use iteration.